# In codeigniter i submit a form by form_open there all button linked by my form_open('Home/page')

Tags: javascript, php, css, html, codeigniter

```html
<?php echo form_open('Home/OtherDetail'); ?>

<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:5%;" >
    <div class="col col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 100%;">Name:</div>
    <div class="col col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><input type="text" name="name" style="width:100%" value=""></div> 
    </div>
    
     <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:5%;">
    <div class="col col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="font-weight: 600;font-size: 100%;">Father Full Name:</div>
    <div class="col col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><input type="text" name="FatherName" style="width:100%" value=""></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:5%;">
    <div class="col col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="font-weight: 600;font-size: 100%;">Address:</div>
    <div class="col col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><input type="text" name="Address" style="width:100%" value=""></div>
    </div>
    
<a href="Home/new"><button >add</button></a>
 <a href="Home/new"><button >negative</button></a>
<?php  form_submit('name',value);      ?>
//so all button which are comes in between from open and form close linked with form_open
<?php  form_close(); ?>
```

//so all button which are comes in between from open and form close linked with form_open

Comment: Could you please add some more information as to what the problem is and what you have tried to fix it.

Comment: Could you please rewrite your question to be a bit more clear? Looking at the posted code, it looks like you're trying to nest forms (opening a form inside another form). That's not allowed in HTML and won't work.

Comment: when i try to do form submit all button get act like submit button in the form

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code and it works perfect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple CodeIgniter App - Todos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo form_open('Home/OtherDetail'); ?>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:5%;" >
            <div class="col col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 100%;">Name:</div>
            <div class="col col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><input type="text" name="name" style="width:100%" value=""></div> 
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:5%;">
            <div class="col col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="font-weight: 600;font-size: 100%;">Father Full Name:</div>
            <div class="col col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><input type="text" name="FatherName" style="width:100%" value=""></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:5%;">
            <div class="col col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="font-weight: 600;font-size: 100%;">Address:</div>
            <div class="col col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><input type="text" name="Address" style="width:100%" value=""></div>
        </div>

        <a href="Home/new">
            <?php echo form_button('add','add'); ?>
            <!-- <button type>add</button> -->
        </a>
        <a href="Home/new">
            <?php echo form_button('negative','negative'); ?>
            <!-- <button type>negative</button> -->
        </a>
        <?php echo form_submit('name','btn_name'); ?>//so all button which are comes in between from open and form close linked with form_open
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want that HTML BUTTON act like Submit, you need to add the tag type="button".

```
<form>
    <button>This button submit</button>
    <button type="button">This button DO NOT submit</button>
    <!-- Default attribute type value is "submit" -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i figure it out why that is happening...
that is happening because of button tag which is in between the form_open tag and form_close tag  as i change button tag to div than it is working perfectly....
so there is the conclusion when you submit the form never use any kind of button tag use only div tag ,span tag etc.

Comment: You can use other buttons in the form too, but in that case you have to prevent the form submit when they are clicked. There are many ways for that, like - <button onClick="return false;">Other Button</button>, Here you can attach a function to the button's onclick method, but that function has to return false. You can use jquery to attach a method and use preventDefault in it to stop the form submit also but that has some pitfalls - which is another topic and has better ways to manage.